# Recover Python file

Tags: python, windows, file, recovery

My computer cut out whilst I was working on a .py file in Idle. I had saved it numerous times, but when I turned my computer back on the file was completely blank. Despite being completely empty in Idle, the file registers as 40KK, which couldn't be possible if there was nothing in it. I'm on Windows 10, and have tried "restore previous options"; nothing came up. I have no file history or backup drive setup. Is the file recoverable, and if so, how?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo up there. Meant to say 40KB, not 40KK.

Comment: You can edit your post.

Comment: This is not a "Python" question...

Comment: Open the file in Notepad. Still empty? Write a python program to read the file in binary mode and dump out the contents and see what is really in it.You could also go to a windows command line and type `type filename.py` and see if it shows any contents.